# Selenium 4 : How to capture screenshot

Tags: hook, screenshot, capture, selenium4

I need an After method to capture a screenshot compatible with **Selenium 4** **Java**

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please add sample code of existing selenium, seems like 3 and then ask for 4. Without code sample its hard to help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@After
public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) Driver.get()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", "screenshot");
    }


    Driver.closeDriver();

}
```