# Selenium/Cucumber: While writing a screenshot file I want to have the Scenarion name in path of the file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

\initialization\DriverUtils.java:

- Here I have a takeScreenshot() function

\steps\Hooks.java

- Here is have a @After where I validate if the scenario.isFailed (io.cucumber.java.Scenario).

In the feature files we declare the tags (and suite) at the beginning:

```
# language: nl
@suite=1A01
@all @aanvraagflow_cv @OK
```

How can I read this @suite property in the @After step so I can pass it to the takescreenshot function (for example).

I am not a real JAVA guru. This is the current implementation. I've read a lot of different ways to implement Selenium / Cucumber in Java. But I can't find a match with mine, that's why my question.

Comment: Try having a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71889101/3324415

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just place a breakpoint in your IDE in the @after hook and run the test in debug mode then evaluate the given step or function and get various attributes